# How to use Jupyter with RISE showing two cells in same slide at same time

Tags: jupyter, cell, rise

I am using Jupyter with RISE, and I want to display a markdown cell with a following code cell below it, in the same slide as a single view without requiring a key press to reveal the markdown and code cells individually. Using a Fragment almost works, but it seems to require user intervention to reveal the second cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. In the Slide Type pull down menu for the second cell you just select the "-" option. I had assumed that that was for skipping the cell from the slide presentation... but it seems to do what I want and just combine it with the previous cell into the same slide. So the first cell gets slide type "Slide" and the second cell gets slide type "-"... and all is cool :)